# Tauri/Rust small program to upload files with use of threads and openssh

Tags: performance, rust, ssh

First time I'm using Rust in one of my programs and I feel a lot can be improved. I don't have any colleagues / friends that already used Rust so this is the only way to get some validation that it's as clean as possible (which it isn't at the moment).

I have quite a lot of experience in Go, Java and Node but somehow I find it a bit hard to adapt to some Rust paradigms, although a lot of it can be transfered over from Go I feel.

I'm building a Tauri application, but I'll only post the Rust part of it since that's where I want to learn from.

## main.rs

```rust
#![cfg_attr(
    all(not(debug_assertions), target_os = "windows"),
    windows_subsystem = "windows"
)]

mod commands;
mod mime;
mod upload;

fn main() {
    tauri::Builder::default()
        .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![
            commands::start_sftp_upload,
            commands::is_mime_safe,
            commands::is_img,
            commands::is_vid,
            commands::is_meta
        ])
        .plugin(tauri_plugin_fs_extra::init())
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}
```

## commands.rs

```rust
use std::sync::mpsc::{self, TryRecvError};
use std::thread;

use tokio::runtime::Runtime;

use crate::mime;
use crate::upload;

#[tauri::command]
pub fn is_mime_safe(filepath: String) -> bool {
    mime::is_img(&filepath) || mime::is_meta(&filepath) || mime::is_vid(&filepath)
}

#[tauri::command]
pub fn is_img(filepath: String) -> bool {
    mime::is_img(filepath)
}

#[tauri::command]
pub fn is_vid(filepath: String) -> bool {
    mime::is_vid(filepath)
}

#[tauri::command]
pub fn is_meta(filepath: String) -> bool {
    mime::is_meta(filepath)
}

#[tauri::command]
pub fn start_sftp_upload(
    window: tauri::Window,
    app: tauri::AppHandle,
    project_dir: String,
    file_paths: Vec<String>,
) {
    let ssh_key_path = app
        .path_resolver()
        .resolve_resource("secrets/inspector-sftp")
        .expect("Failed to resolve SSH key");

    thread::spawn(move || {
        let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
        thread::spawn(move || {
            let rt = Runtime::new().unwrap();
            rt.block_on(async move {
                upload::upload_files_sftp(project_dir, file_paths, tx, ssh_key_path)
                    .await
                    .unwrap();
            });
        });

        loop {
            match rx.try_recv() {
                Ok(val) => {
                    println!("{:?}", val);
                    window.emit("upload_progress", val).unwrap();
                }
                Err(TryRecvError::Disconnected) => {
                    println!("Finished");
                    break;
                }
                Err(TryRecvError::Empty) => {}
            }
        }
    });
}
```

## mime.rs

```rust
use std::path::Path;

pub fn is_img<P: AsRef<Path>>(filepath: P) -> bool {
    match infer::get_from_path(filepath) {
        Ok(opt) => match opt {
            Some(filetype) => {
                filetype.mime_type() == "image/jpeg"
                    || filetype.mime_type() == "image/png"
                    || filetype.mime_type() == "image/gif"
                    || filetype.mime_type() == "image/webp"
                    || filetype.mime_type() == "image/bmp"
                    || filetype.mime_type() == "image/vnd.microsoft.icon"
            }
            None => false,
        },
        Err(why) => {
            println!("Error in infer::get_from_path: {:?}", why);
            false
        }
    }
}

pub fn is_vid<P: AsRef<Path>>(filepath: P) -> bool {
    match infer::get_from_path(filepath) {
        Ok(opt) => match opt {
            Some(filetype) => {
                filetype.mime_type() == "video/x-flv"
                    || filetype.mime_type() == "video/mp4"
                    || filetype.mime_type() == "application/x-mpegURL"
                    || filetype.mime_type() == "video/MP2T"
                    || filetype.mime_type() == "video/3gpp"
                    || filetype.mime_type() == "video/quicktime"
                    || filetype.mime_type() == "video/x-msvideo"
                    || filetype.mime_type() == "video/x-ms-wmv"
            }
            None => false,
        },
        Err(why) => {
            println!("Error in infer::get_from_path: {:?}", why);
            false
        }
    }
}

pub fn is_meta<P: AsRef<Path>>(filepath: P) -> bool {
    let mut info = infer::Infer::new();
    info.add("demo/srt", "srt", is_srt);

    match info.get_from_path(filepath) {
        Ok(opt) => match opt {
            Some(filetype) => filetype.mime_type() == "demo/srt",
            None => false,
        },
        Err(why) => {
            println!("Error in infer::get_from_path: {:?}", why);
            false
        }
    }
}

fn is_srt(buf: &[u8]) -> bool {
    let srt_buf: &[u8] = &[0x31, 0x0A, 0x30, 0x30];
    buf.len() >= srt_buf.len() && &buf[0..srt_buf.len()] == srt_buf
}
```

## upload.rs

```rust
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};
use std::sync::mpsc;

use tauri::api::file::read_binary;
use tauri::api::path::local_data_dir;

use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

use openssh::{KnownHosts, SessionBuilder, Stdio};
use openssh_sftp_client::Sftp;

use walkdir::WalkDir;

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, Clone, Copy)]
pub struct UploadProgress {
    uploaded_files: u32,
    uploaded_bytes: u64,
}

pub async fn upload_files_sftp(
    project_dir: String,
    file_paths: Vec<String>,
    tx: mpsc::Sender<UploadProgress>,
    ssh_key_path: PathBuf,
) -> Result<(), openssh_sftp_client::Error> {
    let mut builder = SessionBuilder::default();
    builder
        .control_directory(local_data_dir().unwrap())
        .keyfile(ssh_key_path)
        .known_hosts_check(KnownHosts::Accept);

    let session = builder
        .connect("inspector@sftp.demo.ai")
        .await
        .unwrap();

    let mut child = session
        .subsystem("sftp")
        .stdin(Stdio::piped())
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .await
        .unwrap();

    let sftp = Sftp::new(
        child.stdin().take().unwrap(),
        child.stdout().take().unwrap(),
        Default::default(),
    )
    .await
    .unwrap();

    {
        let project_path = Path::new(&project_dir);
        let project_location = Path::new(project_path.file_name().unwrap());
        let entries = WalkDir::new(project_path).into_iter();

        let mut upload_progress = UploadProgress {
            uploaded_files: 0,
            uploaded_bytes: 0,
        };

        for entry in entries {
            let entry = entry.unwrap();
            let path = entry.path();
            let filename_with_subfolder_prefix = path.strip_prefix(project_path).unwrap();

            if file_paths.iter().any(|p| p == path.to_str().unwrap()) {
                let file_content = read_binary(path).unwrap();
                let remote_location = format!(
                    "{}",
                    Path::join(project_location, filename_with_subfolder_prefix).display()
                );

                sftp.create(remote_location)
                    .await
                    .unwrap()
                    .write_all(&file_content)
                    .await
                    .unwrap();

                let metadata = entry.metadata().unwrap();

                upload_progress.uploaded_files += 1;
                upload_progress.uploaded_bytes += metadata.len();

                tx.send(upload_progress).unwrap();
            }
        }
    }

    sftp.close().await.unwrap();

    Ok(())
}
```

I'm also having a big performance issue in the upload function, but I hope to figure it out once the code that I have now is up to standards and actually makes sense.